# Relative reduced adjective phrase rephrased as Compound Adjective

Tags: compound-adjectives, participial-phrases

Balloon filled with gas = gas-filled balloon
Infested with mosquito = mosquito-infested
Covered in/with snow = snow-covered
Necklace studded with diamonds = diamond studded
Deprived of sleep = sleep-deprived
Starved of oxygen = oxygen-starved
Soil depleted of nutrients = nutrient-depleted soil
Pizza fried in pan = pan-fried pizza
Based on fact = fact-based
People dependent on drug = drug-dependent people
Matters related to property = property-related matters

However this formation of compound adjective doesn’t hold true in case of almost all participles with specified preposition such as: interested in, amazed at, engaged with, excited about, protected from, convinced of, addicted to, premised upon etc which is a long list. Why? What is the pattern and it's governed by what rules?

I have deliberately avoided passives with 'by' which may appear as post-modifier participle adjectives.

Comment: I noticed that your list has action verbs, not abstractions, and the paired terms call for the  preposition attached. I have heard the term *heroin-addicted*.

Comment: Do you mean: 'Some past participle clauses have corresponding prenominal compound adjectives: << Balloon _filled with gas_ ↔ _gas-filled_ balloon  .... >> However, by no means all do: << _interested in_ ... ... >>. Is there a rule behind these different behaviours?' ?

Comment: interested in, amazed at, engaged with, excited about etc. are not action verbs.  A  necklace studded with diamonds. is not: A book I am interested in.

Comment: @Lambie: I think OP is wondering why *necklace studded with diamonds / diamond-studded necklace* works, while *children excited about clowns / clown-excited children* does not.

Comment: @TinfoilHat To be excited about is not an action verb. Kids love clowns, would be. I wanted to avoid putting in an entire answer when the answer is obvious, which is why I have the example I did in my first comment. Those verbs can't be activated, as it were. Clown-loving kids.

Comment: @Lambie: How is *to be studded with* an action verb while *to be excited about* is not?

Comment: Trying to formulate rules for things like this is a fool's errand. English is just not that regular, and what's acceptable is mostly due to historic accident.